# Creating Side by Side Bars but getting Stack bars

Tags: charts, data-visualization, tableau-api

I am trying to make a side by side bar but I am getting Stacked one.

Columns being used are -

- **Created_On** (Date Format)
- **Closed_On** (Date Format)
- **Count of Issues** (Number format)

I dragged the two date pills into Columns tab and Count of issues in Rows tab. I checked marked the Dual Axis and Sync Axis. After I do that I get stacked(overlapping rather) bars as below, but I should get Side-by-side bars.

The red bars should be next green ones and not overlapping them. Not sure where is it going wrong.

[image: Stacked Bar]

Comment: Have a look through this pal, see if it helps: https://community.tableau.com/thread/165503

Comment: @MyFamily Yes I have, I've followed the same procedure and getting overlapped.